# Error with building libreoffice 4.0.2.2 (in a virtual machine)

Tags: libreoffice, c

I tried to build libreoffice 4.0.2.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 x86-64 using VirtualBox. An error has occurred which says: `no suitable windowing system found, exiting` .

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use the compiled version? Have you installed all neded development libraries?

Comment: from where I can get the compiled version ?
And yes I have installed all the development libraries.

Comment: See below. Just download, extract and install.

Answer (score 0):

The official [wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/How_to_build) says:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice # only on Debian/Ubuntu
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core libreoffice
cd libreoffice
./autogen.sh
make dev-install
```

You can get the compiled version [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect). Just choose x86_64 or x86 and deb.
**Unpack the file:**

- Click on your downloaded package (or right click and do a "Open With" and choose your unpacking tool).
- Extract the folder to a location you have easy access to (your Home directory is fine)

**Installation of the packages**

- Change into the unpacked folder, in it you will see some files  and a DEBS/ folder.
- Change into this folder
- Select ALL files within this folder (except the "desktop integration" folder).
- Do a right-click and in the drop-down menu select something like "Open with Ubuntu Software center"
- You may be prompted to install dependencies, generally the system will tell you if these dependencies will break something.
- Change into the desktop integration folder. This contains a LibreOffice*debian-menus_*.deb file
- Again right-click and open with Ubuntu Software Center to install.

Comment: I've already used those commands but the problem appears when I do the "make" and it looks like this:
no suitable windowing system found, exiting.
make[1]: *** [/home/alloo/lo/workdir/unxlngx6.pro/Gallery/arrows.done]